# event.data.adminRef transactions in Cloud Functions for Firebase getting rejected with permission_denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, google-cloud-functions

I wrote some Cloud Functions for Firebase recently using a testing database with default permissions. When I went to use the functions on the main database (with many permissions) and got a bunch of warnings like:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: transaction at /some/path/to/value failed: permission_denied
```

After some searching I found out about `adminRef` and changed all my `ref`s to `adminRef`s. I triggered the functions again and still got the same errors. Here's the code for one of the functions and the logs that it produces.

```
"use strict";

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const moment = require('moment');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.myFunction1 = functions.database.ref('tree1/{productID}/').onWrite(event => {
    const productID = event.params.productID;

    if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    return event.data.adminRef.root.child('tree2').child(productID).transaction(function (data) {
        if (data === null) {
            return {default: 'value'}
        }
        return data
    }).then(() => { console.log("Transaction finished") });
});
```

The logs:

```
12:09:49.978 Function execution took 2599 ms, finished with status: 'error'

12:09:49.957 Error: permission_denied
    at Error (native)
    at Mh (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:238:437)
    at Ch (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:236:351)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:236:286
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:213:167
    at kh.h.ud (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:214:104)
    at Zg.ud (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:205:364)
    at Qg.Xf (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:203:281)
    at Tg (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:198:109)
    at Client.Ha.onmessage (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:196:467)

12:09:49.950 FIREBASE WARNING: transaction at /tree2/xyz failed: permission_denied
```

Here are the normal rules for these trees

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === 'abc123'",
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'abc123'",
   "tree1": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "tree2": {
      ".indexOn": ["something"],
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried this but the error persists.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    }
  }
```

Comment: I copied and ran your code with rules:  `{".read": "auth != null", ".write": "auth != null"}`.  Didn't see the error.  Is it still failing for you?  Post your security rules.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
exports.myFunction1 = functions.database.ref('tree1/{productID}/').onWrite(event => {
    const productID = event.params.productID;

    if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    return event.data.adminRef.child('tree2').child(productID).transaction(function (data) {
      let default = 0;
      return (data === null) ? default : data;
    }).then(() => { console.log("Transaction finished") });
```

Comment: I made an edit changed `event.data.adminRef.root.child('tree2').child(` to `event.data.adminRef.child('tree2').child(`

Comment: Ah, thanks, I had missed that; still got the error though.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a similar issue regarding to the `transaction` function with `adminRef`.

Take a look here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/16#issuecomment-289094258

Hope it helps.